# Map with just City/Country/River/etc names.

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, maps, qgis-2.8

I am looking for a plug in or a map, that only has the names of the countries and cities and other urban and/or geographical features. Does anyone have or know of such a map/plugin. 
I'v e been searching, but to no avail.

I'm using QGIS. (Wien 2.8.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several free sources like

http://www.statsilk.com/maps/download-free-shapefile-maps

http://www.mapcruzin.com/free-world-country-arcgis-maps-shapefiles.htm

http://www.gadm.org/

You can download them,add to shape files and display labels.

Comment: Tnx, great links!

Answer (score 2):

For place names and admin boundaries, try [NaturalEarth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/10m-cultural-vectors/). They also have natural features like lakes and rivers.

Another good source is [geonames](http://www.geonames.org/).. these come as csv files which you can import into qgis as point layers. They include a mixture of towns, villages but also geographic features like lakes and mountains.

OpenStreetMap is also a good source, and the one I use the most. I use this with the QuickOSM plugin. You'll [need to learn how things are tagged](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features). You could find all villages by looking for 'place=village', for example.

If you want to search for place names, there's an osmSearch plugin.